# XLS VBA : How to sum all values in a row per week, and do that for folowing weeks

Tags: vba, sum, rows, xls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV5ig.png)

So I have the table in the attach, and I would like to ask for you help to understand how sum all info per week, and do that until end of the year, W52,

And in the end I would have to do a subtotal per week by type of task.

I managed put things together and to insert the column for total by week, but I am stucked.

```
Sub insertColumns()


Dim LastCol As Long
Dim sm As Double

Sheets("Raport_Project_Review").Select
LastCol = Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
lRow = Sheets("Raport_Project_Review").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim i As Integer
i = 1
j = 0
Dim nbColAdded As Integer
nbColAdded = 0

While i < LastCol + nbColAdded
    i = i + 8
    j = j + 1
    nbColAdded = nbColAdded + 1
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Insert
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Raport_Project_Review").Cells(2, i) = "W" & j
Wend
```

End Sub

Can you please help with some hints, links on how can I do this using VBA?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcfLu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works

Sub insertColumns()

```
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim sm As Double

Sheets("Raport_Project_Review").Select
LastCol = Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
lRow = Sheets("Raport_Project_Review").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim i As Integer
i = 1
j = 0
k = 3
Dim nbColAdded As Integer
nbColAdded = 0

While i < LastCol + nbColAdded
    i = i + 8
    j = j + 1
    
    
    nbColAdded = nbColAdded + 1
    Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Insert
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Raport_Project_Review").Cells(2, i) = "W" & j
    ActiveSheet.Cells(k, i).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-7]:RC[-1])"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(k, i).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(k, i), Cells(lRow, i))
  
Wend
```

End Sub